# register/unregister `ContentObserver` for events far apart in time

Tags: android, contentobserver

**Scenario :**

I want to register a `ContentObserver` when user logs-in, and unregister it, when user logs-out. The `ContentObserver#onChange()` starts a service that syncs data with server.

**Question :**

The method to unregister `ContentObserver` is `ContentResolver#unregsiterContentObserver()` but this method needs

> previously registered observer that is no longer needed

How to do that ? the login and logout events are far apart in time, how do I keep reference (or maybe *retrieve* using some method ?) to that same `ContentObserver` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do that ?

You need to arrange to hold onto that `ContentObserver` instance somewhere that will live as long as you need it. For example, you might need to hold onto it in a `static` field.

Comment: login and logout event can be hours, days, months or even years apart. `static` cant last that long.

Comment: @ZeekHuge: Since your `ContentObserver` is gone when your process goes away, that does not matter. You cannot have a `ContentObserver` without a process.

Comment: I somehow believed that the `ContentObserver` persists through process kills and startups. Is there something to monitor changes in contacts that would actually persist ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge: On Android 7.0+, you can use `JobScheduler` and `TriggerContentUri` to have what amounts to a persistent `ContentObserver`. There is no option for this prior to Android 7.0.